# Only Allow Login With Spring Security For Users With Certain Roles

Tags: spring, security, authentication, roles, authorize

I have a login page where I want to permit everyone to access the login.jsp. For example,

`<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll()" />`

But I only want to allow access to users with say ROLE_ADMIN. A user with ROLE_USER may be able to successfully authenticate, but they should be redirected back to the login.jsp. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458892/spring-security-redirecting-to-login-page-if-the-authentication-failed, If u think that solves, please consider ur question to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `access-denied-page` on `<http>` to the login page, and protecting URLs properly should have the desired effect.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login">

    <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/page/for/admins"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/page/for/admins" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

</security:http>
```

The user with ROLE_USER will be forwarded back to the login page right after logging in. It's not a pleasant user experience though...